# Is it possible to add animation to a slider created by for loop?

Tags: objective-c, animation, for-loop, uislider

I have create a UISlider for something like a "slider to unlock" element. The animation I've written works well when it point to just one slider. But I need to use a for loop to create sliders dynamically. And the animation does not work when I create the sliders add tags for the sliders and add the animation function to the sliders in the for loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
    ...
    UISlider *slider=[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5+ xInc, 25+yInc, 322, 40)];
    //give a id tag to the slider
    [slider setTag:i*10];
    //set a action to the slider
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(UnlocklinkSlider:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ...
```

And the animation function is:

```
- (void)UnlocklinkSlider:(UISlider*)slider
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < rownumber; i++){
        UIImageView *frontimg = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i*10+1];
        ...
        if (slider.tag==i*10) {
            if(slider.value >= 0.5){
                // user did not slide far enough, so return back to 0 position
                [UIView beginAnimations: @"SlideCanceled" context: nil];
                [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.35];
                // use CurveEaseOut to create "spring" effect
                [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
                ...
                [UIView commitAnimations];
                ...
            }
            else{
                ...
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

But the animation does not work in this way. Does anybody know why?

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop? What properties are you trying to animate? In what way does it not work?

Comment: Actually, it for creating a slider button, if I slide to the very left side and click, it will go to web page 1, if I slide to the very right side and click, it will go to web page 2, if I slider to neither the very left or right side it will return to left or right. These buttons are links to certain web sites with two different accesses -- web page 1s and web page 2s, I can add buttons to different web sites by a uitableview.

Comment: Ok, sure, but you get passed the slider, why are you looping rather than using the slider to work out what to do?

Comment: And I want to write a animation to the slider letting it not return so quickly, but the animation of the slider does not work.

Comment: looping is to create plural sliders, each slider has two accesses

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the `[UIView beginAnimations]` and `[UIView commitAnimations]` outside of the loop.

If that doesn't work, you can try using [CoreAnimations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW1) on the layers of the views.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the newer block based animation API to control the duration while setting the value of the slider:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
    [slider setValue:1];
}
```

Also, you have 2 different loops but you should probably only have 1. You want a loop to create all of your sliders and add them to the view. But, when you get a callback from one of the sliders you do not want a loop. Instead you should interact only with the slider that called the action (that is the one that the user is interacting with).

Comment: There is no reason for them not to work in a for loop. I still don't get why you have a for loop. More likely you have something that is explicitly disabling animations (what code is in the ... sections?).

Comment: Cause I have to create sliders for all the web sites in the sqlite data base, so I have to use a for loop to read all the rows and create a slider for each row.

Comment: I first save all the rows in a array, "rowCount" is the number of rows in the data base, then I use for loop to create slider for each row